# How do I find out what version my Skyrim is patched to?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

[Today's Skyrim patch has some unfortunate side effects](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1284360-concerning-the-small-patch-through-steam-today/). I've turned off updates for the game in Steam for the time being, but I can't find anywhere that indicates whether it's already been updated or not.

Steam and silent patching aside, it's useful to know what version of the game you're running, especially once mods start depending on specific versions. How can I find out?

Comment: Aside, looks like the patch did apply, since I'm getting CTDs all over now. Still want to know how to check this though.

Comment: I swear I've seen the version number in my game before when I brought up the tab menu... I'll see if I can elaborate once I get home.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start/load a game, press ESC to bring up the system menu, and it's there near the bottom left hand corner.
[image]

Answer (score 13):

There's no direct way in Steam. However it's possible by checking the Skyrim executable's metadata. Go to you steam installation folder, then browse to \steamapps\common\skyrim .

Right click the TESV.exe file and select properties. The version number should be displayed in the details tab.

[image]

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Windows XP should also show this information, though possibly in a different way; look for a `Version` tab under `Properties`, instead of `Details`.

Comment: I could swear there were only three tabs when I looked. It's there now, though! Alas, they appear to have declined to change the version number. The backup and the updated EXE, with different sizes and behaviours, have the same Windows EXE version number: `1.1.21.0` :-/